# how to fix Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 error?

Tags: ios, xcode8

I am getting this issue of architecture?

```
   Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
      "_CGImageGetWidth", referenced from:
          GetBytesFromCGImage(CGImage*, int*, int*, int*) in OSInference.o
      "_CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB", referenced from:
          GetBytesFromCGImage(CGImage*, int*, int*, int*) in OSInference.o
      "_CGBitmapContextCreate", referenced from:
          GetBytesFromCGImage(CGImage*, int*, int*, int*) in OSInference.o
      "_CGImageGetHeight", referenced from:
          GetBytesFromCGImage(CGImage*, int*, int*, int*) in OSInference.o
      "_CGColorSpaceRelease", referenced from:
          GetBytesFromCGImage(CGImage*, int*, int*, int*) in OSInference.o
      "_CGContextDrawImage", referenced from:
          GetBytesFromCGImage(CGImage*, int*, int*, int*) in OSInference.o
      "_CGContextRelease", referenced from:
          GetBytesFromCGImage(CGImage*, int*, int*, int*) in OSInference.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What I have done

1. In Build Phase - Link binary with libraries I have added 
   AVKit, CoreGraphics, QuartzCore

2.Build Architecture only - NO

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Try  to change Build Active Architecture Only" to YES

Comment: Thank You, but getting error like ----- No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=arm64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1-** Add `CoreGraphics` framework into your project

**2-** Import `CoreGraphics`

**3-** Clean your project

**4-** Try to Build again

Comment: I second that. Please make sure you are importing it in relevant source files and add it to the project (in build phase, as you are doing).